# Upgrading From 11.04 (32bit) to 12.04 (64bit)

Tags: 12.04

I'm upgrading from 11.04 i386 to 12.4 64x. What I mean is I've installed the 12.4 64x server and I want to get all the settings from the 11.04 to set up the 12.4, the settings I'd like to get are for apache / PHP / phpmyadmin etc. Any and all settings that have to do with the web server. What files should I get or what path should I take here? Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your configurations, your PHP settings should be in `/etc/php5/*`.

I do not know where phpmyadmin stores its data on the system.

I also do not know where your website files are.  but your Apache settings should be in either `/etc/httpd/*` or `/etc/apache2/*`, where `*` is a wildcard meaning everything within that folder.

Those folders contain the files for your configurations, and should be saved.  As well, any relevant user data should be saved as well (`/home/user/*` for example, where `user` is your username.)

Comment: Would I just copy the folders over to the new system and restart it?

Comment: You would not just "restart", you'd need to save your data onto some type of external media, and then *clean install* 12.04 64bit, since you cannot go directly from 32bit to 64bit.  Then you would need to manually go through and restore your data from the external storage.  As well, you'd need to reinstall all the packages again, some of which have had name changes since 11.04.

Comment: "clean install" means a brand new installation from the installation media, a 12.04 DVD or USB stick with the installation software image on it.

Comment: BTW these are both VMs. I have a fresh install of the 12.4 so now I just install/update all the services/programs I need. Then get the "etc/" folders for each and copy those over?

Comment: No, you first clean-install each service/program you need (`sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server php5 ...` depending on what you need, of course), then you copy your configs over.  Then you copy your files over.  Then you restart each service accordingly, and hope that it doesnt blow up.  If it blows up, there's something wrong.  but that'll be a different question.

Comment: Understood. I'll get on that and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Everything worked out fine. Thanks for the tips.